# Laravel 5 Auth::attempt() always returns false

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel and I'm stuck in authentication. I've no idea what's wrong with this code, can someone help me with this?  I've read a lot of answers in here in Stackoverflow and so far none of them worked.

I've made a simple code just to test `Auth::attempt()`. Most of the tutorials that i've followed was using this simple code. Is there something else that i need to configure before the Auth works? Why is this so complicated?

P.S.
I've also tested if it's generating correct hash and it seems to be fine.

**Controller:**

```
public function index()
{

    $user = new User;
    $user->email = 'q21@q.com';
    $user->password = Hash::make('123456');
    $user->save();
    $userData = array('email' => 'q21@q.com', 'password' => '123456');            

    var_dump(Auth::attempt($userData));

}
```

**Model:**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

protected $table = 'users';

protected $fillable = ['email', 'password'];

protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
```

}

Update... Below is my migration script for user table.

I have a separate login for admin  and user, maybe this is causing the problem. It is possible that it's not looking at the right table because the admin auth works. How do i display the SQL used in Auth?

**User table Migration script**

```
Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('firstname');
        $table->string('lastname');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function()
{

    Route::post('user/login','UserController@login');

    Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth','jwt.refresh']], function()
    {
        Route::resource('user','UserController');
    });
});


Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function()
{

Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index');
Route::get('login', 'AdminController@postlogin');
Route::post('login', 'AdminController@postlogin');

Route::get('logout', function(){
    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::to('admin');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function()
{
    Route::resource('messages', 'MessageController');
});

});
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `Auth::attempt` inside the registration form?

Comment: What does your migration look like?

Comment: @aldrin27 because i wanted to automatically login the user after registering.

Comment: If you want to automatically logged in the user don't use auth attempt. Just redirect him in your dashboards page.

Comment: @Jazerix this is my migration for user table

Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
  {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->string('firstname');
   $table->string('lastname');
   $table->string('email')->unique();
   $table->date('dob')->nullable();
   $table->string('contact')->nullable();
   $table->string('password');
   $table->string('profile_img')->nullable();
   $table->timestamps();
  });

Comment: @aldrin27 but i have a middleware to check if the user is logged in or not.

Comment: So your index is inside the middleware?

Comment: @aldrin27 nope, middleware was defined in my routes. Index is in my controller.

Comment: Can you also show your config/auth.php and also schema for creating admin table? Do you use Auth class for authorizing admins too?

Comment: Can we see your routes?

Comment: @aldrin27 Thanks for helping me. I've found the problem. I've overriden Auth Database config by adding `Config::set('auth.model', 'App\AdminUser');` in the constructor. Now it's using the AdminUser model instead of User model.

Comment: That's good to hear. Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you do not setup your database properly.

In order to make Eloquent ORM work, it must have a database. The related config should be at config/database.php , then you should check whether such table exists. On the other hand, it is possible you do not set up your connection correctly in your Eloquent, if you are not expected to connect to your default database in config/database.php

Minor point, also make sure your config/auth.php is doing it correctly. auth.php should work with your codes under default setting.

Comment: I've check auth config and DB setting it works fine. I think there's a conflict on admin and regular user login.